# instances of virus transmission-enhancing research approvals

Tags: virology

In February 2019 this article by epidemiologist Marc Lipsitch and professor Tom Inglesby raised concern about secret virus research.

[Washington Post article link.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/the-us-is-funding-dangerous-experiments-it-doesnt-want-you-to-know-about/2019/02/27/5f60e934-38ae-11e9-a2cd-307b06d0257b_story.html)

> In 2014, U.S. officials imposed a moratorium on experiments to enhance
> some of the world’s most lethal viruses by making them transmissible
> by air, responding to widespread concerns that a lab accident could
> spark a global pandemic. Most infectious-disease studies pose modest
> safety risks, but given that these proposed experiments intended to
> create a highly contagious flu virus that could spread among humans,
> the government concluded the work should not go on until it could be
> approved through a specially created, rigorous review process that
> considered the dangers.
>
> Apparently, the government has decided the research should now move
> ahead. In the past year, the U.S. government quietly greenlighted
> funding for two groups of researchers, one in the United States and
> the other in the Netherlands, to conduct transmission-enhancing
> experiments on the bird flu virus as they were originally proposed
> before the moratorium. Amazingly, despite the potential public-health
> consequences of such work, neither the approval nor the deliberations
> or judgments that supported it were announced publicly. The government
> confirmed them only when a reporter learned about them through
> non-official channels.

Have there been other instances of transmission-enhancing research approvals since the apparent end of the moratorium?